# Error resolving template "welcome", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddJv7.png)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>spring-boot-web-thymeleaf</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Spring Boot Web Thymeleaf Example</name>
<description>Spring Boot Web JSP Example</description>
<url>https://www.mkyong.com</url>
<version>1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hot swapping, disable cache for template, enable live reload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
<!-- This is a web application -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tomcat embedded container-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP,
        tomcat-embed-jasper version is not working, no idea why -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

SpringBootWebApplication.java

```
package com.mkyong;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

WelcomeController.java

```
package com.mkyong;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

// inject via application.properties
@Value("${welcome.message:test}")
private String message = "Hello World";

@RequestMapping("/")
public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("message", this.message);
    return "welcome";
}

}
```

[output error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgYFX.png)

**welcome.jsp page is not accessing**

**If welcome.jsp is replaced by welcome.html then output is coming properly(no issue in this case)**

**but i am not getting how to access welcome.jsp file in this Spring Boot application**

**why html is accessing and why jsp is not accessing ?**

**please give the solution**

Comment: Instead of .jsp file please try using .html. And you are missing the following Dependancy  `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

i think it was Spring version : I change version to 1.4.1, then> mvn clean install      it's worked for me.and i use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

hope it helps